# Array displays words by each letter than than words. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to JS and I'm trying to populate a dropdown menu with items from an array but every time I loop through the array it displays letter after letter rather than the full string. Please let me know what am I doing wrong. Thank you

JS:

```
var ProjectNames = [];
ProjectNames = CProject;
var select = document.getElementById("ProjectList");
for (var i = 0; i < ProjectNames.length; i++) {
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    console.log(ProjectNames[i]);
    var opt = ProjectNames[i];
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="ProjectList" onchange="AddHoursForm()">
<option> --Choose Project-- </option>
</select>
```

Data in array is coming from Firebase. If I print console.log(ProjectNames) it gives the array objects but if I do console.log(ProjectNames[i]) it prints it letter by letter.

Comment: What is `CProject`?

Comment: could it be that your CProject is a string that needs to be converted to an array with .split(',')

Comment: CProject was a variable rather than array with values from Firebase. @Nestoro I used your method and worked perfectly. Thank you for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working for me. Make sure you are working with an array.

```js
var ProjectNames = [];
ProjectNames = ["hello", "world"];

console.log(ProjectNames)   // <--- check this is this array?

var select = document.getElementById("ProjectList");
for (var i = 0; i < ProjectNames.length; i++) {
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  console.log(ProjectNames[i]);
  var opt = ProjectNames[i];
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  select.appendChild(el);
}
```

```html
<select id="ProjectList" onchange="AddHoursForm()">
  <option> --Choose Project-- </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what it was. When I populated my array from CProject it got entered letter by letter rather than word by word because CProject wasn't an array.

Answer (score 0):

You killed the contents of ProjectNames setting it equal to CProject.

If you want to add itemns to ProjectNames use `push` or `ProjectNames[ProjectNames.length]=...` as below: The rest is ok.

```
var CProject="four";
var ProjectNames = ["one","two","three"];
ProjectNames[ProjectNames.length]=CProject;
ProjectNames.push("five");

var select = document.getElementById("ProjectList");
for (var i = 0; i < ProjectNames.length; i++) {
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    console.log(ProjectNames[i]);
    var opt = ProjectNames[i];
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- It would be really easy for you if you use template strings or template literals for achieving this.
- Just get data, create element, append it upon your ease.

```js
// selecting div ith id = "main"
const main = document.querySelector("#main");
// you data from firebase or any other data source
let data = ["option1", "option2"];
// creating an element using tamplate string
const mySelectElement = `
<select>
<option value="" disabled selected>Choose a option</option>
${data.map(option => `<option value="${option}">${option}</option>`).join('')}
</select>
`;
//appeding element
main.innerHTML = mySelectElement;
```

```html
<div id="main">
</div>
```